# Finding a specfic variable in a class array

Tags: java, arrays

Hi there I have an object array and I want to be able to have a method that looks through the Class array nameList and find a specific last name and then returns the instance that matches the last name with both the first and lastname.

```
Name[] nameList= new Name[] {
    new Name("Mason","Akman"),
    new Name("Ethan","Aldo"),
    new Name("Pi","Manly"),
    new Name("Shu","Hing"),
    new Name("Mane","Dove"),
    new Name("Minky","Maduno")}:
```

What I have so far is

```
public Name lookup(String lastname) {
    for (Name lookup : nameList) {
          if (lookup.equals(lastname)) {
             return nameList;
          } else {
             continue;
          }
        }
}
```

However this wont work as I cant convert from Name[] to Name. Cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong any help would be appreciated.

edit: here is the name class

```
public class Name {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Name(String firstName,String lastName) {
    this.setFirstName(firstName);
    this.setLastName(lastName);
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String toString() {
    return "First Name: "+this.firstName+
            "Last Name: "+this.lastName;
}
```

}

Comment: `if(lookup.lastname.equals(lastname)) return lookup;` and there is no need for `else` condition.

Comment: This won't compile without a `return` statement being executed in the case nothing matches.

Comment: outside the loop, add a `return null;`

Comment: if possible please also share the content of Name class. It helps us to structure the answer.

Comment: added the Name class

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1) the return type expects a Name to be returned a the entire nameList
2) The method must return something, so outside of your for loop, you need to add a return statement and can return a default null if a matching name was not found.

```
public Name lookup(String lastname) {
    for (Name lookup : nameList) {
        if (lookup.getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
            return lookup; //Changed this line to return lookup (a Name) instead of nameList
        } 
//      else { //The else is unnecessary
//          continue;
//      }
    }

    return null; //Added this as a default return when no matching name was found
}
```

Comment: Changed "if (lookup.equals(code)) {" to "if (lookup.equals(lastname)) {" because I mistyped code in there when I meant.  However I get a warning saying Unlikely argument for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to Name

Comment: Thanks and I see - corrected in answer - need to call getLastName() to get the lastname of the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

1. A non-void method should have a return value for all branches. You have a if statement and you prepare the return for the true case, which is good. Also you need to prepare a return for the false case (or any other else-if). If you don'
   t, eventually you have to return something before you leave the method.
2. The return value type should match with the method signature. You declare the method as 
   `public Name lookup(String lastname)`. It should return a Name, not an array of Name.
3. Object.equals() available to all instances. But if you want to lookup a Name by checking their **last name**, you should do equals() check on that attribute

   ```
   public Name lookup(String lastname) {
       for (Name lookup : nameList) {
           if (lookup.getLastName().equals(lastname)) { // check the input parameter against the lastName attribute of the Name object, not the Name itself
               return lookup; // if a match is found, return the name and end this routine
           } else { // unnecessary, but not an error. for-loop will push the iteration forward, you don't have to do it yourself
               continue;
           }
       }

       return null; // if this line is reached, means no matched is found, return a null
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be accomplished with java-8 Stream API.
Just create a stream, filter for the searched `lastname` and return the first
`Name` instance that passes the filter. Otherwise return `null`.

The below code should work as long as the provided `lastname` is not `null`:

```
 public Name lookup(String lastname){
        return Arrays.stream(nameList)
                .filter(n -> lastname.equals(n.getLastName()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
 }
```